# IBM MobileFirst 6.3 asynchrous APIs

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How can we handle asynchronous ApI call for example if have following line of code

1. WL.connect (onsucces:SuccessCallback,onfailure:Failure-callback);
2. Mycustomfunc()
3. mycustomfunc2()

Now due to slow network or whatever reason line 2 and 3 executed even before 1 , how can we make sure that line executed only when SuccessCallback finish?

Line 1 is one example but we also have same issue when we r calling xmlhttp request in hybrid app.

What could be the best solution to handle this issue ? Interesting thing is that we are frequently getting this on windows environment.

Comment: Call mycustomfun at the end of the success callback?

Comment: Thanks we are doing the same way but one suggestion was to use busyindicator ? What about second part of my question related to windows

Comment: I don't understand what busy indicator has to do with it. You need to write coherent questions. The functions will not get executed if you do not call them outside of the success/failure functions. Add larger timeout values.

Comment: Suggestion was to call busy.show before line 1 and hide() before line 2 if we do not want to call line 2 code inside successCallback

Comment: Again, what does busy indicator has to do with it? Busy indicator only displays a busy indicator, it will not stop any function execution.

Comment: Thanks Idan making it clear , understanding was that if u call busy.show() and on second line call any asynch function and then call busy.hide() so hide() will not execute until that asynch function completes and if there is another function after hide() it will not be called in other words busy.hide() will put hold

Comment: I suggest you gain a better understanding of callbacks (and promises) in general.  This will hopefully solve a lot of the confusion you are facing currently. 

Couple of valuable pointers....  
https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks and 
http://callbackhell.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want `MyCustomfunc()` to be executed only when the success callback is ready, then you should simply place it within our success callback function 
Here is an example

```
WL.Client.connect (  { onSuccess : successCallback , onFailure : failureCallback }); 


function successCallback(response){ 
  myCustomFunc(); 
}
```